# GIT merge conflict: after create new branch and deleting some files

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a problem with a GIT merge. In fact, I have a master branch with this architecture:

```
.git
doc
   \__ some files

src
   \__ tools 1
              \__ some files

   \__ tools 2
              \__ some files
```

In my project, I developed tools and I will add other tools in the "src" directory. For that, for each time I want to create a new tool, I will create a new branch named "tools3" from master branch and then remove all directories that I do not need, here "tools 1", "tools 2" and "doc". The reason is that I do not need documentation and other tools to develop.

So now, after those deleting I code my "tools 3" and I commit and push it into the new branch "tools3". It's time to merge my two branches with a `git merge tools3 -m "Merge tools3 branch with master branch"` (in master branch).

I have two problems, first some conflicts among with documentation files:

**CONFLICT MESSAGE:**
`CONFLICT (modify/delete): doc/api_project.json deleted in tools3 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of doc/api_project.json left in tree.`

In the second time, the merging removes my "src" files (the ones I deleted earlier in "tools3" branch).

So, how can I fix this merge conflict and then how can I retrieve my removing files in master branch? I think I do not have the best practice to do this type of things with GIT so I am open to any suggestions about GIT practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mustn't delete the files from the repo you don't need. This is the reason you get the conflict(s).

While you've been working in your `tools 3` dir, other contributors may have worked in them. E.g. fixing bugs, adding new features, etc. They've completed their work and pushed it to `master`.

When its time for you to do push your work, history has diverged. Since you started your branch, on one hand you've deleted some files, and on the other these files have been changed by other people. Git can't make the decision on what the correct route to take is, so it creates a conflict.

You only really want to delete a file from a git repo if it is no longer useful for the entire project and no longer need it source controlled. To me it looks like you are only deleting them because you want to keep your directory structure "clean" or some other reason we can only speculate on.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I would like to delete the other tools in the "src" folder to "clean" my project but it is not a good solution as you said. So, thank you one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create new tool you are creating the branch by cloning your master branch. once you added a new tool into the newly created branch, you are comparing the master and newly created branch in the background. So whatever the new changes are there will be added in the master branch and what is the modified changes will be updated/removed from the master branch. So you must not delete the code from any branch as it will be removed at the time of merging.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict you're encountering is because another person has made a change in `master` to one of the files that you have deleted in `tools3`. As a result, when you're attempting to merge git needs to work out how to apply the changes that were made in `master` to a file that you deleted before the changes were made.

Visual representation:

```
*   - Added doc/api_project.json
|\
| * - Deleted doc/api_project.json
| |
* | - [master] Updated doc/api_project.json
  |
  * - [tools3] Dev work on tools
```

As you can see above, to put those commits in to a single branch, git needs to know how to apply the changes made in the third commit to a file deleted in the second commit.

You shouldn't make any changes in a branch which do not apply to the feature that you're working on in that branch. By deleting files, you've created a commit that deletes those files.

Hopefully you performed the deletion as a separate commit (can we see `git log` output for your `tools3` branch?) which would mean all you'd need to do is remove that commit from your branch before merging.

Removing the deletion operations will solve both your problems, you'll no longer have a conflict and the files that are being removed from the `master` branch (because you deleted them in `tools3`) will no longer be removed.

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem, but it is more a problem with the way that I use GIT more than a "real" GIT problem but thanks for your time.

Comment: I can highly recommend https://learngitbranching.js.org/ if you feel like you need to understand git better to get the best out of it. It's a great interactive tutorial and it will help cement a good understanding of how git works.

Comment: Thank you @AdamNierzad for your advice.